# Generating symmetric Positive Definite Matrix from random vector multiplication yield singular matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

This might seem a very naive or ignorant question, but I am not able to give myself a satisfactory explanation.

Suppose i want to generate a random symmetric positive definite matrix. I was under the impression that every matrix that follows,
$$
x^TAx > 0\\ ~\forall x \ne0 \in R
$$
is a positive definite matrix. So if I take a random vector > 0 and multiply it with its transpose I should get a positive definite matrix. However octave disagrees!

```
x = rand(5,1)*5;
A = x*x'
ans =

    7.6497    3.5375    4.7485    6.9960   13.1888
    3.5375    1.6359    2.1959    3.2352    6.0990
    4.7485    2.1959    2.9476    4.3427    8.1869
    6.9960    3.2352    4.3427    6.3982   12.0618
   13.1888    6.0990    8.1869   12.0618   22.7388

chol(A)
error: chol: input matrix must be positive definite
```

Should the above matrix not be positive definite?
When i dug up further, i found out that some of its eigenvalues are negative but even adding small diagonal part and making them positive didnt help, it only worked once I add values > 1e-14 to diagonal

```
eig(A)
ans =

  -8.4114e-16
  -4.2296e-16
   1.1886e-16
   5.4291e-15
   4.1370e+01

eig(A + eye(5)*1e-15)
ans =

   4.4863e-16
   5.0505e-16
   1.1676e-15
   7.9287e-15
   4.1370e+01


chol(A + eye(5)*1e-15)
error: chol: input matrix must be positive definite

chol(x*x' + eye(5)*1e-14)
ans =

   2.76581   1.27901   1.71686   2.52947   4.76852
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

1.) what is the surest way of generating a symmetric positive definite matrix with a random vector?
2.) how much diagonal value I need to add?

I again apologize if this question seem bit juvenile or ignorant. I am trying to grasp linear algebra.

Comment: Your matrix is rank one, which means it has only one nonzero eigenvalues and 4 zero eigenvalues. Thus it is positive semidefinite

Comment: Try to generate $X=\mathrm{rand}(5,5)$ and then use $X^TX$

Comment: OK. that makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply vector $x$ by its transpose $x^T$, you will get positive semidefinite matrix with only one nonzero eigenvalue.

Instead you can generate $X=\mathrm{rand}(5,5)$ and set $A=X^TX$. Or you can also generate diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements and perform unitary transformation, i.e. $UDU^*$, where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is unitary.